# how to redirect to html page when serve address is put into url

Tags: apache-http-server

I have an apache server running on `<myserverip>` when someone typed the server ip into the url it gives the forbidden page which is good but i want it so that it redirects the page to `<myserverip>/test.html`. What file do I specify that in?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your httpd.config file.
editing httpd.conf could be tricky if you are newbie and don't have proper knowledge.

I can tell you another way to redirect direct IP access to some other page.
you can do it by adding a .htaccess file in your root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^SERVER_IP$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* SERVER_IP/test.html [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all your ip calls to IP/test.html

Comment: so I would add this to my apache2.conf?